# Resolve Hostname Error When Accessing Subversion

Tags: svn, hostname, resolve

I get the an error when attempting to do the following commands in Subversion:
update, commit, log, list, blame etc.
However, diff and info work.

The error is the following when using any desktop client, e.g. CollabNet, TortoiseSVN, Intellij, Visual Studio's AnkhSVN:
"http://xxx01/comm/JavaService/trunk/: Could not resolve hostname
`http://xxx01/comm': The requested name is valid and was found in the
database, but it does not have the correct associated data being
resolved for."

This only occurs on my laptop (not colleagues) and only started occurring this week after
administrators changed the password for the account Subversion uses to authenticate. The error does not occur when I'm using remote desktop to another machine or accessing subversion via the web.

Thanks in advance for any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: What URL does a subversion info show - I'm not sure how you do that in your subversion clients but on the command line it is 'svn info'

Comment: Could not resolve host name? I guess something is wrong with your DNS server setting.

Comment: Not related to programming? migrate to superuser.com

Comment: Why not connect by IP address? That won't change and should always resolve.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like your proxy server settings need to be updated.  Subversion keeps all of these settings in a text file named "servers" (no extension).

In Windows, this file is located in %APPDATA%/Subversion/ (e.g. C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application Data\Subversion).

1) Open "servers" and make sure that all data for your proxy server is correct.  There should be directions in the file on how to change your password, but it will involve changing these lines:

```
[GLOBAL]:
http-proxy-host = proxyserver.example.com
http-proxy-port = 80
http-proxy-username = yourusername
http-proxy-password = yourpassword
```

2) Also, sometimes **Tortoise SVN** keeps active an incorrect proxy setting.  If you have Tortoise installed, whether or not you're using it (especially if you're using **Subclipse**): open the Tortoise Settings GUI, navigate to 'Network' and make sure the settings are correct under 'Enable Proxy Server'.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have a default domain in your desktop settings, compare the output of

`nslookup xxx01` from your desktop and laptop. You could also use a fully qualified name like `xxx01.acme.com` in your SVN URL.

Comment: snv info shows the correct repository root url: http://xxx01/comm

nslookup xxx01 displays the same info on both laptop and remote desktop and resolves to the correct alias xxx01.acme.com. Also, using the fully qualified name or the ip address in the url does not affect the outcome.

Comment: @David Since you're using http (Port 80) and I assume that you can surf the web. I have no better idea than disabling firewall. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Sockets Error Codes:

> The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does
>   not have the correct associated data
>   being resolved for, e.g. an MX record
>   is returned but no A record -
>   indicating the host itself exists, but
>   is not directly reachable.

Sometimes after some changes to hostnames it requires several reboots
(or a few hours waiting) until those changes fully are used (due to
caching).

Or there might be a firewall/proxy/virus scanner interferring.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to resolve this issue. I did find some malware on my machine a corrupt file, but none of this resolve the issue. In the end, I recored the machine, reinstalled TortoiseSVN ... and voila! It fixed the problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ran into this issue, probably because some `.svn` files were corrupt. I created a new folder and let the **tortoisesvn** check out the whole version. It works.