# The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for

Tags: tortoisesvn

I use the TortoiseSVN to checkout source code from URL (browser) and get Error as follows :
Could not resolve hostname : The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for.

I have seen similar error being reported in this forum but wonder what was the exact solution to resolve the said error.

Among solutions proposed were :

1. 'Everything was fixed by yet another reboot (2 reboots after TSVN update).'

   - posted Nikolay R
2. 'The solution for me involved setting the appropriate proxy settings within Tortoise
   SVN -> Settings -> Network (which were already setup in my browser, hence being able
   to view the repository fine there). So if you are behind a proxy server, make sure 
   you setup TSVN appropriately'

   - posted by Chris

May I know what TSVN/network settings were changed to resolve this error?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve Hostname Error When Accessing Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344077/resolve-hostname-error-when-accessing-subversion)

Comment: Could you add the following information: Changes in your `TortoiseSVN > Settings > Network`, do you need a proxy where you are located, has that folder you want to update worked in the past in the same network at the same location? This would gives us some indication which kind of problem you have.